# Two 60% elements in a single container

Tags: html, css

I try to copy (sort of) single post presentation design from certain website. Here is how it looks like: 
[image]

(antyweb.pl)

Apparently they use "A" element and the image is its background. I don't like this idea as it requires to put some dummy text that we won't see anyway.

At this point - let me show how I would like to do it:

[image]

What I have is an `article` element employed as container. Inside there are two other elements with max-width for img and width for div set to `61.8033988749854683%`.

How to make it so that the div and the image will be displayed right below the header at the same height?

So far I failed as the div was overlapping over the content below while resizing or when it had enough text in it to make it higher than the image.

Thanks in advance, much love

-edit 1-

first [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MM5hs/4/).

-edit 2-

another container added in order to get text where it belongs to: http://jsfiddle.net/MM5hs/5/

What happens now is that the text from first article overlaps another article: http://jsfiddle.net/MM5hs/6/

Comment: Please show us a fiddle.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `floats`.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/MM5hs/15/)**

HTML :

```
 <article>
        <header>
            <h2><a href="#">Header</a></h2>
        </header>
        <div name="topline">
            <div class="img_wrap">
                <img src="http://cdn.desktopwallpapers4.me/wallpapers/animals/1920x1200/1/3634-kitten-1920x1200-animal-wallpaper.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div name="content">
                <p>... content ...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="auth">  
            <span>Author: 
                <a href="#" title="zobacz wszystkie posty tego autora">me</a>, 
                <time datetime="2014-04-04T01:48:23+00:00">2014-04-04T01:48:23+00:00</time>
            </span>
        </div>
    </article>
```

CSS :

```
article {
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
}
div[name*="topline"] {
    position:relative;
}
div[name*="content"] {
    max-width: 61.8033988749854683%;
    margin-left: 38.1966011250145317%;
}
.img_wrap {
    width:38.1966011250145317%;
    float:left;
    overflow:visible;
}
article img {
    width: 150%;
}
.auth {
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: @user3496885 background of what? and what do you mean by "working properly"?

Comment: That was just silly me... I set background to content div, but the image was "between" background and text. Now I've got overflow set to image wrap and it works just perfect